# Counting classes then specify the amount to change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following JavaScript function where I am counting the total `divs` with a `classname`, but not all must be changed, that is specified with the amount param. So there are 4 classes, so the each counts the classes and then the for loop changes them according to the amount param.

Yet this doesn't seem to work, see commented out version too -

```js
function changeImages(change, amount) {
  var $projImg = $('.proj-img');

  $.each($projImg, function(i) {
    $(this).attr('src', 'src/img/' + change + 'Slide' + (i + 1) + '.png');
  });

  // $.each($projImg, function (j) {
  //     for(var i = 0; i < amount; i++){
  //         $(this).attr('src', 'src/img/' + change + 'Slide' + (i) + '.png');
  //     }
  // });

}
```

Comment: `var $projImg = $('.proj-img').slice(0, amount);`

Comment: could u pls share your image path which you are setting in attr()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an array and then `slice` it so that it contains no more than the `amount` number of elements, no jQuery required:

```
function changeImages(change, amount) {
  const projImgs = [...document.querySelectorAll('.proj-img')]
    .slice(0, amount);
  projImgs.forEach((img, i) => {
    img.src = 'src/img/' + change + 'Slide' + (i + 1) + '.png';
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use jQuery's [`.slice()`](https://api.jquery.com/slice/):

```js
function changeImages(amount) {
    const $matches = $('.foo').slice(0, amount);

    $matches.addClass('bar');
}

changeImages(10);
```

```css
.foo {
  border-bottom: 8px solid red;
}

.bar {
  border-color: cyan;
}

.foo:hover {
  border-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo"></div>
<div class="foo"></div>
<div class="foo"></div>
<div class="foo"></div>
<div class="foo"></div>

<div class="foo"></div>
<div class="foo"></div>
<div class="foo"></div>
<div class="foo"></div>
<div class="foo"></div>

<div class="foo"></div>
<div class="foo"></div>
<div class="foo"></div>
<div class="foo"></div>
<div class="foo"></div>

<div class="foo"></div>
<div class="foo"></div>
<div class="foo"></div>
<div class="foo"></div>
<div class="foo"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Your JS code would then look like this:

```js
function changeImages(change, amount) {
  $('img').slice(0, amount).each((i, el) => {
    el.setAttribute('src', `https://place-hold.it/200x200&text=${ change }-${ i + 1 }`);
  });
}

changeImages('UPDATED', 3);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

img {
  float: left;
  max-width: 20vw;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://place-hold.it/200x200&text=DEFAULT" />
<img src="https://place-hold.it/200x200&text=DEFAULT" />
<img src="https://place-hold.it/200x200&text=DEFAULT" />
<img src="https://place-hold.it/200x200&text=DEFAULT" />
<img src="https://place-hold.it/200x200&text=DEFAULT" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Also, regarding [`:lt()`](https://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/), keep in mind that's not part of the CSS specification, as stated in the docs:

> Because `:lt()` is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification, queries using `:lt()` cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM `querySelectorAll()` method. For better performance in modern browsers, use `$("your-pure-css-selector").slice(0, index)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `:lt()` selector

```js
   var amount = 5,change = '';
   $('.proj-img:lt('+amount+')').map(function(i,el){
        $(el).attr('src', 'src/img/' + change + 'Slide' + (i + 1) + '.png');
    });
    console.log($('.proj-img'))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="" alt="" class="proj-img">
    <img src="" alt="" class="proj-img">
    <img src="" alt="" class="proj-img">
    <img src="" alt="" class="proj-img">
    <img src="" alt="" class="proj-img">
    <img src="" alt="" class="proj-img">
    <img src="" alt="" class="proj-img">
    <img src="" alt="" class="proj-img">
    <img src="" alt="" class="proj-img">
    <img src="" alt="" class="proj-img">
    <img src="" alt="" class="proj-img">
    <img src="" alt="" class="proj-img">
    <img src="" alt="" class="proj-img">
    <img src="" alt="" class="proj-img">
    <img src="" alt="" class="proj-img">
    <img src="" alt="" class="proj-img">
    <img src="" alt="" class="proj-img">
    <img src="" alt="" class="proj-img">
    <img src="" alt="" class="proj-img">
    <img src="" alt="" class="proj-img">
```